# Creating modals on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to create a new and unique modal everytime I click one of the divs. The problem is that when I click in the divs the new modal is created, but does't open like it should.

If I click the button before clicking one of the divs, the default modal opens normally.

**HTML**

```
<div class="destaque1">Gráfico 1</div>
<div class="destaque2">Gráfico 2</div>
<div class="destaque3">Gráfico 3</div>
<div class="destaque4">Gráfico 4</div>

<button id="myBtn">Open Modal</button>

<div id="myModal" class="modal">
   <div class="modal-content">
      <span class="close">&times;</span>
      <p>Some text in the Modal..</p>
   </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.modal {
   display: none;
   position: fixed;
   z-index: 1;
   padding-top: 100px;
   left: 0;
   top: 0;
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
   overflow: auto;
   background-color: rgb(0,0,0);
   background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
}

.modal-content {
   background-color: #fefefe;
   margin: auto;
   padding: 20px;
   border: 1px solid #888;
   width: 80%;
}

.close {
   color: #aaaaaa;
   float: right;
   font-size: 28px;
   font-weight: bold;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
   color: #000;
   text-decoration: none;
   cursor: pointer;
}
```

**SCRIPT**

```
var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');

var btn = document.getElementById("myBtn");

var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

btn.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "block";
}

span.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "none";
    $('#myModal').remove();
    $('.modal-content').remove();
    $('.close').remove();
}

window.onclick = function(event) {
    if (event.target == modal) {
        modal.style.display = "none";
        $('#myModal').remove();
        $('.modal-content').remove();
        $('.close').remove();
    }
}

$('.destaque1').click(function(){

    $('#myModal').remove();
    $('.modal-content').remove();
    $('.close').remove();

    var divModal = document.createElement('div');
    divModal.id = "myModal";
    divModal.className = "modal";

    var divModalContent = document.createElement('div');
    divModalContent.className = "modal-content";

    var spanClose = document.createElement('span');
    spanClose.className = "close";

    var t = document.createTextNode("times;");
    spanClose.appendChild(t);

    document.body.appendChild(divModal);
    divModal.appendChild(divModalContent);
    divModalContent.appendChild(spanClose);

    modal.style.display = "block";
    modal.style.backgroundColor = "red";

});

$('.destaque2').click(function(){

    $('#myModal').remove();
    $('.modal-content').remove();
    $('.close').remove();

    var divModal = document.createElement('div');
    divModal.id = "myModal";
    divModal.className = "modal";

    var divModalContent = document.createElement('div');
    divModalContent.className = "modal-content";

    var spanClose = document.createElement('span');
    spanClose.className = "close";

    var t = document.createTextNode("times;");
    spanClose.appendChild(t);

    document.body.appendChild(divModal);
    divModal.appendChild(divModalContent);
    divModalContent.appendChild(spanClose);

    modal.style.display = "block";
    modal.style.backgroundColor = "blue";

});

$('.destaque3').click(function(){

    $('#myModal').remove();
    $('.modal-content').remove();
    $('.close').remove();

    var divModal = document.createElement('div');
    divModal.id = "myModal";
    divModal.className = "modal";

    var divModalContent = document.createElement('div');
    divModalContent.className = "modal-content";

    var spanClose = document.createElement('span');
    spanClose.className = "close";

    var t = document.createTextNode("times;");
    spanClose.appendChild(t);

    document.body.appendChild(divModal);
    divModal.appendChild(divModalContent);
    divModalContent.appendChild(spanClose);

    modal.style.display = "block";
    modal.style.backgroundColor = "green";

});

$('.destaque4').click(function(){

    $('#myModal').remove();
    $('.modal-content').remove();
    $('.close').remove();

    var divModal = document.createElement('div');
    divModal.id = "myModal";
    divModal.className = "modal";

    var divModalContent = document.createElement('div');
    divModalContent.className = "modal-content";

    var spanClose = document.createElement('span');
    spanClose.className = "close";

    var t = document.createTextNode("times;");
    spanClose.appendChild(t);

    document.body.appendChild(divModal);
    divModal.appendChild(divModalContent);
    divModalContent.appendChild(spanClose);

    modal.style.display = "block";
    modal.style.backgroundColor = "yellow";

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you remove `#myModal` from the DOM tree and create a new element with that ID, your `modal` is not updated and therefore still points to the removed element.

I suggest you restructure your code as follows:

- You move everything that deals with the variables `modal` and `span` into a separate function (I'll call it `initModal`).
- You make `initModal` show the modal (i.e. set `modal.style.display = 'block'`).
- You make `initModal` return the `modal`, so that customizations like background color can easily be applied after initializing it.
- You set `btn.onclick = initModal`.

All that applied, you get:

```js
var btn = document.getElementById("myBtn");

btn.onclick = initModal;

function initModal()
{
 var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');
    var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

    span.onclick = function() {
        modal.style.display = "none";
        $('#myModal').remove();
        $('.modal-content').remove();
        $('.close').remove();
    }
    
    window.onclick = function(event) {
        if (event.target == modal) {
            modal.style.display = "none";
            $('#myModal').remove();
            $('.modal-content').remove();
            $('.close').remove();
        }
    }
    
    modal.style.display = "block";
    return modal;
}

$('.destaque1').click(function(){

    $('#myModal').remove();
    $('.modal-content').remove();
    $('.close').remove();

    var divModal = document.createElement('div');
    divModal.id = "myModal";
    divModal.className = "modal";

    var divModalContent = document.createElement('div');
    divModalContent.className = "modal-content";

    var spanClose = document.createElement('span');
    spanClose.className = "close";

    var t = document.createTextNode("times;");
    spanClose.appendChild(t);

    document.body.appendChild(divModal);
    divModal.appendChild(divModalContent);
    divModalContent.appendChild(spanClose);

    initModal().style.backgroundColor = "red";
});

$('.destaque2').click(function(){

    $('#myModal').remove();
    $('.modal-content').remove();
    $('.close').remove();

    var divModal = document.createElement('div');
    divModal.id = "myModal";
    divModal.className = "modal";

    var divModalContent = document.createElement('div');
    divModalContent.className = "modal-content";

    var spanClose = document.createElement('span');
    spanClose.className = "close";

    var t = document.createTextNode("times;");
    spanClose.appendChild(t);

    document.body.appendChild(divModal);
    divModal.appendChild(divModalContent);
    divModalContent.appendChild(spanClose);

    initModal().style.backgroundColor = "blue";
});

$('.destaque3').click(function(){

    $('#myModal').remove();
    $('.modal-content').remove();
    $('.close').remove();

    var divModal = document.createElement('div');
    divModal.id = "myModal";
    divModal.className = "modal";

    var divModalContent = document.createElement('div');
    divModalContent.className = "modal-content";

    var spanClose = document.createElement('span');
    spanClose.className = "close";

    var t = document.createTextNode("times;");
    spanClose.appendChild(t);

    document.body.appendChild(divModal);
    divModal.appendChild(divModalContent);
    divModalContent.appendChild(spanClose);

    initModal().style.backgroundColor = "green";
});

$('.destaque4').click(function(){

    $('#myModal').remove();
    $('.modal-content').remove();
    $('.close').remove();

    var divModal = document.createElement('div');
    divModal.id = "myModal";
    divModal.className = "modal";

    var divModalContent = document.createElement('div');
    divModalContent.className = "modal-content";

    var spanClose = document.createElement('span');
    spanClose.className = "close";

    var t = document.createTextNode("times;");
    spanClose.appendChild(t);

    document.body.appendChild(divModal);
    divModal.appendChild(divModalContent);
    divModalContent.appendChild(spanClose);

    initModal().style.backgroundColor = "yellow";
});
```

```css
.modal {
   display: none;
   position: fixed;
   z-index: 1;
   padding-top: 100px;
   left: 0;
   top: 0;
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
   overflow: auto;
   background-color: rgb(0,0,0);
   background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
}

.modal-content {
   background-color: #fefefe;
   margin: auto;
   padding: 20px;
   border: 1px solid #888;
   width: 80%;
}

.close {
   color: #aaaaaa;
   float: right;
   font-size: 28px;
   font-weight: bold;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
   color: #000;
   text-decoration: none;
   cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="destaque1">Gráfico 1</div>
<div class="destaque2">Gráfico 2</div>
<div class="destaque3">Gráfico 3</div>
<div class="destaque4">Gráfico 4</div>

<button id="myBtn">Open Modal</button>

<div id="myModal" class="modal">
   <div class="modal-content">
      <span class="close">&times;</span>
      <p>Some text in the Modal..</p>
   </div>
</div>
```